# Sum array of objects with dynamic keys - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I've got the following array

```js
arr = [
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 2, 'Caja': 3 },
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 1 },
  { 'Tarifa Social': 3 }
]
```

Expected output: 9

And I would like to sum the properties the shortest way possible. The thing is that the object keys are always variable so i can't go for:

```js
arr.reduce((acc,item) => acc+item.keyName)
```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868697/reduce-array-of-objects-with-dynamic-keys) post but can't adapt the code to my solution either:

```
var data = [{ A: 4, B: 2 }, { A: 2, B: 1 }, { A: 3, B: 1 }, { A: 2, B: 1, C: 1 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => (Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + v), r), {});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Andy answer i'm looking is 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution. Map through the array and flatten the properties values, then reduce them.

```js
const arr = [
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 2, 'Caja': 3 },
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 1 },
  { 'Tarifa Social': 3 }
]

console.log(arr.flatMap(e => Object.values(e)).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
```

Comment: This is what I was loking for, thanks! It seem easier in my head than it really was

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce twice, once on the outer array and once on the values of each object inside it.

```js
const arr = [
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 2, 'Caja': 3 },
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 1 },
  { 'Tarifa Social': 3 }
];
const total = arr.reduce((gt, item) => 
  gt + Object.values(item).reduce((t, sub) => t + sub, 0)
, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
let acc = {};
for (let o of arr) for (let key in o) {
    acc[key] ??= 0;
    acc[key] += o[key];
}
```

Not a one-liner though

Comment: Yeah, thoght of that but I'm trying to improve my javascript skills. Thak's!

Comment: @juanmac, there's nothing wrong with making code make more sense. One-liners are difficult to comprehend.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
total = arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
     const values = Object.values(item)
     values.forEach(item=> acc += item)
    return acc;
}, 0);
```

Check I passed the first value (0) as the second parameter to reduce method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr = [
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 2, 'Caja': 3 },
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 1 },
  { 'Tarifa Social': 3 }
]
var total = 0;
arr.forEach((x, i) => 
    total += Object.values(x).reduce((a,b) => a+b)
);
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help:

```js
arr = [
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 2, 'Caja': 3 },
  { 'Atencion Personalizada': 1 },
  { 'Tarifa Social': 3 }
]

 var sum = arr.map(item => {
    var x = 0
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
        x+=value
    }
    return x
}).reduce( (acc, curr) => acc + curr)
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve it with this approach:

- use `JSON.stringify` to get arr as string.
- extract numbers with match with regex `\d+` and flag `g` to return it as group.
- map it to real numbers rather than string.
- reduce it to the sum of all numbers.

```js
JSON.stringify(arr) //'[{"Atencion Personalizada":2,"Caja":3},{"Atencion Personalizada":1},{"Tarifa Social":3}]'
.match(/\d+/g) //['2', '3', '1', '3']
.map(Number) //[2, 3, 1, 3]
.reduce((acc, n)=>acc+n, 0) //9
```