# flatten array of objects with dynamic keys and sum only values with "_abs" in key name

Tags: javascript

**I have an array of objects that looks like this:**

```
[{"A_abs":4,"A_perc":2, "B_abs":4,"B_perc":2, ...},{"A_abs":4,"A_perc":2, "B_abs":4,"B_perc":2, ...},{"A_abs":4,"A_perc":2, "B_abs":4,"B_perc":2, ...},{"A_abs":4,"A_perc":2, "B_abs":4,"B_perc":2, ...}]
```

There can be up to `n` elements in each object, each one consists of a _perc and an _abs value.
I want to reduce the array to only 1 entry and sum each _abs value, the _perc can be anything else, like "-".

**An expected result would be:**

```
{"A_abs": 16, "A_perc": "-" "B_abs": 16, "B_perc": "-"  "C_abs": x, "C_perc": "-", ...}
```

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59868773/7195155) of this question does not fully statisfy me because I don't know how to adapt the function to only sum the "_abs" values.

How to adapt this function to only sum the _abs values, regardles of how many entries the object has?

```js
var data = [{"A_abs":4,"A_perc":2, "B_abs":4,"B_perc":2},{"A_abs":4,"A_perc":2, "B_abs":4,"B_perc":2},{"A_abs":4,"A_perc":2, "B_abs":4,"B_perc":2},{"A_abs":4,"A_perc":2, "B_abs":4,"B_perc":2}],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => (Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + v), r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want to sum up all the `A_ABS`?

Comment: I want to sum all _abs , ignoring the _perc values.

Comment: The final object will have all the `_abs` keys, for ex: `a_abs`, `b_abs`, `c_abs` etc and all of them would have same value i.e. their sum?

Comment: @SSM, correct, the final object should have all `_abs` and their sums

Comment: @toffler Please check the answer below probably it does what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the `key` [ends with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) `_abs` and only if it does you add the values else you simply assign a value of `-`.

```js
const data = [
    { A_abs: 4, A_perc: 2, B_abs: 4, B_perc: 2 },
    { A_abs: 4, A_perc: 2, B_abs: 4, B_perc: 2 },
    { A_abs: 4, A_perc: 2, B_abs: 4, B_perc: 2 },
    { A_abs: 4, A_perc: 2, B_abs: 4, B_perc: 2 },
  ],
  result = data.reduce(
    (r, o) => (
      Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) =>
        k.endsWith("_abs") ? (r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + v) : (r[k] = "-")
      ),
      r
    ),
    {}
  );

console.log(result);
```